# I don't know how to select h1 with css selector in this html....which one is the right ClassName for div?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this html :

```
 <div class="d-flex align-items-center flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between w-100 pt-10 pb-15">
   <h1 class="product-title mb-0 pl-10 order-2 order-sm-1 ml-auto ml-sm-0" itemprop="name">
    Samsung Galexy A70
   </h1>

</div>
```

which one is true???

this selector??

```
div.d-flex align-items-center flex-column flex-sm-row justify-content-between w-100 pt-10 pb-15 h1{

}
```

or this one?

```
div.d-flex  h1{

}
```

Comment: Your first one matches.... `<div class="d-flex"><align-items-center><flex-column><flex-sm-row><justify-content-between>.....`

Comment: Specificity is what matters most. Using id over classes, using classes over elements. div h1 is least specific while your first answer is most specific. It will be more specific once you use pseudo elements and pseudo classes. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Answer (score 2):

Most likely what you want is just:

```
.product-title {
  // styles go here
}
```

When you separate CSS selector elements with a space, that is using a [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Combinators#Descendant_selector). This means that a selector like this:

```
div.parent h1 {
  // styles go here
}
```

would target the `<h1>` element here:

```
<div class="parent">
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your first approach is wrong second one is good

Best is use class `product-title` on `h1`like

```
.product-title{color:red;}
```

or if your class in reusable then a tag as well like

```
h1.product-title{color:red;}
```

You can also select tag itself like

```
h1{color:red;}
```

All depend to your requirement

[Read more about CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much verbose the first one until it works.

Consider this:

**`h1`** is a direct son of your **`div`** because is inside of it, so at this point it could be much simpler in this way:

```
div h1
```

Or even better with **BEM** through it's class identifier

```
.main-container__main-title
```

Consider this example with a BEM approach

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>Example</title>
      <style>
        .main-container__main-title {
          color: red;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="main-container">
      <h1 class="main-container__main-title">Hola</h1>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Where...

- My main container has an eloquent `class`
- h1 that belongs as a son of your main container has a class with a similar name but at the end I have added **`__main-title`** to identify this element